# How to save photo to directory

Tags: ios, uiimage, directory, save

I created multiple directories using

```
NSArray *directoryNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"t",@"b",@"p",@"c", @"S", @"h", @"o",nil];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

for (int i = 0; i < [directoryNames count] ; i++) {
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryNames objectAtIndex:i]];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
```

However I want to sort the photo that is displaying on the UIImage and sort it which the user select using pickerview.  I want to know the code to save into these specific directory that I made.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Update I know that

To use your created directories anywhere in your app.

```
NSArray *directoryNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tops",@"bottoms",@"right",@"left",nil];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

// This will return the folder name in the 0 position. In yours "tops"
NSString *topDirPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryNames objectAtIndex:0]];
// This will return the file path in your "tops" folder
NSString *filePath = [topDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MYIMAGE"];
```

To store an image file

```
NSData *imageDataToStore = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageDataToStore writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

I do not know where to declare my directory name

Comment: I found this line in an old project [self.library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:img.CGImage metadata:nil completionBlock:nil]; But im not 100% sure it works :P

Comment: @Arbitur Thats for Photo Album .....

Comment: oops sry, I mixed it with something else :S

Answer (score 1):

To save images to a file in a folder you need to get the data for the image (`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`) and then save that data to disk (`writeToFile:atomically:`).

Comment: I do not now simply where to declare my directory name updated answer

Comment: I don't understand. Which directory name? I thought your question said the directory name was chosen from a picker?